adding snow effect to game scene with SpriteKit
I'm trying to add snow effect to my game scene by using SKEmitterNode. Since the game scene is quite large (25600 x 32000 pixels), I ended up adding the particle effects to the scene camera node. It does give the effect of there is snow falling where ever I go. However, it also causes issues. Since the camera is fix on the player character, therefore, the snow moves around the camera as player moves about. Whenever player moves upward the snow drifts upward as well. When player moves downward the snow seems falling at double speed. The snow also shifts left and right as player moves left and right.
My Question is: is there a way to make the snow falling independent of player movements.
If it needs to be added directly to the scene instead of the camera node, how to make it covers the entire scene?
Thanks in advance for any help.

You can fake it with a new SKNode bound to the view frame with the snow emitter added to that layer.  It would behave the same as a HUD layer except instead of your player's life bar it would have snow particles.  Then your scene could be infinitely large and it will only show snow through the currently viewable area.  The user will never know that there is no snow off screen.

Thanks Gallonallen, in fact I did try to add the emttier to my HUD layer (which is a SKNode added to the camera node) but it didn't make any difference. What did I do wrong?

I found the solution to my problem. Set the emitter's targetNode = scene
